# How do I mention a previous US visit using an OCI card?

Tags: visas, india, us-citizens, applications

My minor son travelled to India 7 years ago with a OCI card. Now I and my son are traveling to India again. He now has a new US passport, which is different than the one mentioned on his OCI card 7 years ago. I'm now applying for an e-visa for him.

There  are mandatory questions asking about the 'last visa number used' and the 'type of visa used'.  If I put his OCI number as the previous visa number (since OCI is a lifelong multiple entry, multipurpose visa), then what can I choose as 'visa type' ?
 'Entry visa' seems like the most appropriate choice, but I'm not sure. Also 'lifelong visa' is not an option under visa type.

Comment: Why e-visa rather than updating his OCI card?

Comment: Also, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overseas_Citizenship_of_India#History), an OCI card and a currently valid US passport would be sufficient even if the passport number does not match. Have you checked whether he needs any new paperwork?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan People under the age of 20 need to [renew their OCI card](https://mha.gov.in/PDF_Other/FAQOCIMiscservices_25042017.pdf) when they get a new passport. It's not clear why he is trying to get an e-visa at all.

Comment: user has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold.